# Can't get body data on server using C# code

Tags: c#, api

I'm trying to send a json content inside the body. But unfortunately, I don't get the data in the server. Same data is received using postman tool.

Here is the code I'm running

```
private string callAPI(string function, string content)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        string url = function;
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", txt_sessionKey.Text);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrlV2);
        var json = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {                    
                Method = HttpMethod.Put,
                RequestUri = new Uri(baseUrlV2+function),
                Content = json
            };
        HttpContent contentRes = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result.Content;

        return contentRes.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: please add the content string as this is probably an error in your json syntax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serialize and Deserialize Json and Json Array in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239705/serialize-and-deserialize-json-and-json-array-in-unity)

Comment: What is the HTTP status code and result you get? Also it may help to show the postman console trace of the request. As it is there is no way to do anything but guess.

Comment: Here is the json i'm sending

{"requestID":"12345678", "data":{"content" : "{"configurationData":{"ip":"192.168.20.229"},"type":"configuration"}","method":"Fast"}}

I'm reaching the server (mine) and getting a response, but without the json

Comment: Well, i fixed the json format and now i'm still getting partial  data. in addition now i'm getting the requestid 

the json is 

{
  "requestID": "12345678",
  "data": "ew0KICAidHlwZSI6ICJjb25maWd1cmF0aW9uIiwNCiAgImNvbmZpZ3VyYXRpb25EYXRhIjoge30NCn0=",
  "method": "Fast"
}